# Laravel Envoy show error but don't show evironment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-envoy

I have a problem with Laravel Envoy. 
I'm wrote script for deploying on server and I'm calling that script with 
**envoy run deploy --environment=staging** 
 but when error occur, I can't see from what production is error. 
For example, error occur on  php artisan migrate and I can catch task where error occur but I can't get environment. 
Here is my code:

```
@error

@slack('hook', '#deploy', "Deploy failed on {$environment} error: 
$task")
exit;
@enderror
```

And the output on slack channel deploy is:
**Deploy failed on   error: migrate-db**

Comment: {{$environment}}.  ???

Comment: @HelderDeBaere
just add before setup and endsetup character@
     setup
        $environment = isset($env) ? $env : "staging";
    endsetup

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Envoy script has an error in the `migrate-db` task. Without posting the code, it's hard to tell what's happening with that task. I'd suggest using a simple `echo` within the task to get the script to complete first.

Run `envoy run deploy --env=staging`

```
@servers(['web' => '127.0.0.1'])

@setup
    $env  = isset($env) ? $env : "localhost";
    $host = gethostname();
    $hook =  "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX";
    $channel = "#your-channel";
@endsetup

@story('deploy')
    migrate-db
@endstory

@task('migrate-db')
    echo 'migrate-db'
@endtask

@error
    @slack($hook, $channel, "Deploy failed on [$env], hostname: $host");
    echo "Deploy failed on [$env], hostname: $host\r\n";
@enderror

@finished
    @slack($hook, $channel, "Deploy succeeded on [$env], hostname: $host");
    echo "Deploy succeeded on [$env], hostname: $host\r\n";
@endfinished
```